# Layout override of admin com_users

Tags: joomla-3.x, layout

I am trying to override the layout views of `com_users` in the admin side.

I have copied all view of `com_users` ie:

`com_users/views/user/...`

and copied it to the administrator template ie:

`templates/isis/html/com_users/user/...`

however no changes reflect on changing the template files , what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might have got muddled up with the template.

If you're trying to override the view for the front-end of your website, you need to copy the view files to the front-end template. By default, it will be Protostar, **not** Isis

You have 5 different views with the `com_users` component:

- Login
- Profile
- Registration
- Remind
- Reset

So if you want to override the Login view, you need to copy the PHP files from here:

```
components\com_users\views\login\tmpl
```

and your end result will be:

```
templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default.php
templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default_logout.php
templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default_login.php
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Got it , i was copying the `tmpl` folder too which was causing the issues !

Comment: Ahh yes, this can catch people out sometimes :)

Comment: Just one more thing  , how can 'amodule' in a view file ?

Comment: @jimmyobonyo - I'm not sure what you mean by this...could you explain please?

Comment: soory i mean how can i 'put' ie call a module in the layout overide vie ie the `default.php` view i want to put a module called `mod_something`

Comment: @Lodder - thanks for the edit on my answer below.. I was looking at the paths and knew that I was missing something... but for some reason I was unable to realize it.

Comment: @jimmyobonyo - I'd firstly have a look at [JModuleHelper::renderModule](https://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/renderModule) which does this. Then ask a new question if you have any issues with it ;)

Comment: @jimmyobonyo - I read your comments about modules overrides. I am sure you can find a lot of posts dealing with it. If you can't find, I would suggest to ask a new question, rather than extending the initial question to other topics through comments.

Comment: @Lodder :-) , of course , of course

Answer (score 5):

You should not copy the full view folder, only the template files of a particular view, that you want to override.

So for example, the following file needs to be copied:

```
administrator/components/com_users/views/user/tmpl/edit.php
```

and placed in:

```
administrator/templates/isis/html/com_users/user/edit.php
```

The difference here is that you should not include the tmpl folder, inside the overrides folder.

Comment: @lodder - thanks for the edit .. I was looking at the paths and knew that I was missing something... but for some reason I was unable to realize it.